# Как подписать jar-файлы?

Tags: javaws, java, цифровая-подпись

Как подписать jar-файлы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Проверить наличие `JDK`.
2. Получить `pfx`-файл.
3. Проверить, что `keytool` читает `pfx`-файл.

   $ keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore файл.pfx
4. Подписать `jar`-файл.

   $ jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore файл.pfx файл.jar

Answer (score 1):

еще удобно использовать Ant, т.к. можно подписывать группу архивов и не набирать этот текст каждый раз (предполагается, что keystore у вас есть):

> ```
>   <target name="sign-jar"> 
>     <signjar keystore=".keystore"
>              alias="alias123"
>              storepass="pass123">
>       <path>
>         <fileset dir="${some_dir}" includes="*.jar" />
>       </path>
>     </signjar>
>   </target>
> ```